# Container fluid not centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just want my columns to be centered but there's just too much space on the right side no space on the left.

```
<div id="about" class="pad-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">COMPANIES</h1>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="margin: 150px 0 100px 0;">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom"><a href="#">
          <div class="img">Image with hovering effect</div>
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Description</p>
          </div></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom"><a href="#">
          <div class="img">Image with hovering effect</div>
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Description</p>
          </div></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom"><a href="#">
          <div class="img">Image with hovering effect</div>
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Description</p>
          </div></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. `</div></a></div>` huh?

Comment: Your HTML is fine. That is how fluid containers work, they take up 100% of the width of the page. This is the expected result of your code. If you want it to be centered then remove the fluid container.

Comment: @APAD1 how can I make it centered tho? :(

Comment: @PraveenKumar lol I just saw that thanks for pointing it out but still didn't solve my problem?

Comment: Change `container-fluid` to `container`, then it will have a set width and it will be centered on the page: http://www.bootply.com/s8IRU9e3wc

Comment: @APAD1 Oh I did that before but the columns were too close to each other and I tried putting paddings but still didn't work 'cause they're contained in a fix width(?)

Comment: You can override the default padding values for the columns if you want there to be more space between them.

Comment: @APAD1 I did, I can see it changing when add in 1 column but when I do it with the other 2 columns it stays the same because they have to remain in the fixed width... :(

Comment: Bootstrap columns don't use fixed widths, they use percentages. If you override the default column padding it will apply to all columns.

Comment: @APAD1 lol thanks okay I changed the % and it kinda worked but now it's off-centered...

Answer (score 1):

you need to change from `.container-fluid` to `.container` and `.row-fluid` to `.row`

**UPDATE** OP's Comment:

> Thank you but my problem with that is the columns are too close to
>   each other even when I add paddings?

you have to override the `padding` for the columns (don't use `!important`) I had to use because the snippet wouldn't work, set the value as you like it more for the `padding`.

> Also it's not centered on smaller screens

To align center use bootstrap class `text-center`,

**Note:** plus I used `col-xs-4` but only for demo here, if you want to have one column only, use `col-xs-12` or `col-sm-12`

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0 50px !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="pad-section" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">COMPANIES</h1>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 150px 0 100px 0;">
      <div class="text-center col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="img">
              Image with hovering effect
            </div>
            <div class="info">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="img">
              Image with hovering effect
            </div>
            <div class="info">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="img">
              Image with hovering effect
            </div>
            <div class="info">
              <h3>Title</h3>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem with that is the columns are too close to each other even when I add paddings?

Comment: Just three :) and 1 on the smallest screen

Comment: @NikitaLim, see updated answer, you have to override the padding for the columns as I did (don't use `!important`) I had to use because the snippet wouldn't work, set the value as you like it more for the padding. To align center use bootstrap class `text-center`, plus I used `col-xs-4` but only for demo here, if you want to have one column only, use `col-xs-12` or `col-sm-12`

Comment: Thank you! I changed the percentage to 80% and they kind of spread out but now they're not centered

Comment: what percentage? can you show a fiddle for that? did you run my snippet?

Comment: Here I tried to change the width to 80%. Yes I ran yours and it's working perectly but when I put this hovering efffect on the image it messes up.
https://jsfiddle.net/zbkrurv2/

Comment: If you'd notice it's not centered on smaller screens too

Comment: Im not at the computer right now.. Will be in a few hours only approx 3h to 4h.. Then carefully ill look into your new fiddle..

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @NikitaLim, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye64069h/) , the issue is because you have fixed `width` \ `height` for `.square` (and if you decide to have `.circle` you need to remove them too)