# Center a bootstrap container-fluid horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I center my main container horizontally, using excising bootstrap classes

here is the container:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
        <div class="col-md-10 content">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Edit existing questions 
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[The way it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX1TA.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Container fluid not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943368/container-fluid-not-centered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/w4gLtcz5/1/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 content">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
             Edit existing questions 
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In **bootstrap**, by **default** there is **12 columns**.

Since your container is **occupying 10 columns out of 12**, so started your container from 2 column instead of column 1. So that in both the side of the container you will have equal space.

I considered **col-md-10** is your number of columns

I have added **col-md-offset-1**.

Comment: aaaa.. not working, no idea if anymore or newer were. chrome wind 10

Comment: @Sangoku What error you are getting? Please explain on the issue.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBF1R.png
it just straight up does not work on my pc on fidget to.

Comment: Hello! How is this centered horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

Please use **col-xs-offset-x**
Instead of x you can write number between 1 to 12.

Move columns to the right using .col-md-offset-* classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns:

Your code will be.

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
    <div class="col-md-10 content col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Edit existing questions 
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp